# toISOString() changes datetime value

Tags: javascript, datetime, timezone

I have array of the objects.Each object in array has date property.I try to get biggest(the last) date from array.

Here is array:

```
var sensorsData = [{
  Id: 1,
  MeasureDate: "2017-08-20T09:52:32"
}, {
  Id: 2,
  MeasureDate: "2017-08-20T09:54:35"
}, {
  Id: 3,
  MeasureDate: "2017-08-20T09:56:13"
}];
```

And here is function the fetch the biggest date from array above:

```
function updateLatestDate(sensorsData) {
  return new Date(Math.max.apply(null, sensorsData.map(function(e) {
    return new Date(e.MeasureDate);
  }))).toISOString();
}
```

the result that I get from `updateLatestDate` function is:

```
2017-08-20T06:56:13.000Z
```

but it strange because, as you can see no one of the properties in sensorsData objects doesn't  have the date as returned from `updateLatestDate` function.

Here is [FIDDLER](https://jsfiddle.net/xf5jmLL6/6/).

Any idea why updateLatestDate function returns wrong result?

Comment: My be you'd like to see another working solution based on yours, with slightly different angle of looking at the problem

Comment: @Michael - What is the `MeasureDate` field reflecting?  Is it time in a particular time zone?  Ideally it would be in UTC, but your data doesn't include such detail.  That is the ultimate source of the problem.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

When you create a date with `new Date(str)` it creates a date object with a time zone. `toISOString()` makes it zero UTC offset, as denoted by the suffix "Z".

Here is a workaround:

```
var date = new Date(e.MeasureDate)
return new Date(date.getTime() - date.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000)
```

Updated fiddler: https://jsfiddle.net/xf5jmLL6/7

`getTimezoneOffset` returns number of minutes and `new Date` expects number of milliseconds since January 1 1970 00:00:00 UTC, so multiplying by 60000 provides needed adjustment.

Comment: This assumes the input is indeed in terms of local time - or at least that there are no local-time discontinuities in the data.  Also, there is no such thing as a `Date` object with a time zone.  All that is happening here is that the input string is being treated as local time because it doesn't contain any offset.  If the OP meant the input to be treated as UTC, then simply appending a `Z` to the input string would fix the entire problem.

Comment: Also, the shifting approach shown here can lead to errors near local time discontinuities, such as DST transitions.  If you are going to shift like that, you can only use the UTC-based functions going forward, which are now actually returning the local time. You can get the ISO string, if you trim off the `Z`, but you should not return a `Date` object, as it would be representing a different point in time.

Comment: I know it's an old issue, but a VERY helpful answer.
For those (like TiggerToo) wondering what's the "magic number", its how much milliseconds are in a minute. getTimezoneOffset returns the offset in minutes, while Date operates on milliseconds, so we need to convert (hence multiplication by 60k).

Answer (score 1):

The problem lay in that this process (that makes date conversion to integers than back to dates) is not reversible
the proof is in the following function that performs conversion from dates to int and then back to dates, only to get different values from the starting ones

```html
<button onclick="setDate()">irreversible conversion</button>
<script>
   
function setDate(){
var sensorsData = [{Id:1,MeasureDate:"2017-08-20T09:52:32" },{Id:2,MeasureDate:"2017-08-20T09:54:35" },{Id:3,MeasureDate:"2017-08-20T09:56:13"}];

function irreversible(){
          sensorsData.forEach(function (e){
            console.log(
                 new Date(
                      new Date(e.MeasureDate).getTime()
                 )
             );
          })        
        } 
        
        irreversible();
}        

</script>
```

My solution is pretty simple : comparing dates as are, and returning the result

```js
function setDate(){
var sensorsData = [{Id:1,MeasureDate:"2017-08-20T09:52:32" },{Id:2,MeasureDate:"2017-08-20T09:54:35" },{Id:3,MeasureDate:"2017-08-20T09:56:13"}];

var lastDate = updateLatestDate(sensorsData);
console.log(lastDate.MeasureDate);


function compare(d1,d2){
if (d1.MeasureDate >d2.MeasureDate)
  return d1;
else
  return d2;
}

function updateLatestDate(sensorsData) {
      return ( sensorsData.reduce(compare) );
  }
}
</script>
```

```html
<button onclick="setDate()">update date</button>
```